# How to combine material tab's with swiper slider? Framework7

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, html-framework-7

I'm working with Framework7.
Is it possible to combine the material tab's with the swiper slider?
I want to make tabs accessible over tabbing the tab-bar. And also want to swipe to the next “tab” by swiping left/right. Is that possible? I tried this, but it doesn't work for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <title>Soziale Medien durchsuchen</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/framework7.material.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/search.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class=“views”>
        <div class=“view view-main”>
            <div class=“pages”>
                <div data-page=“home” class=“page toolbar-fixed navbar-fixed”>
                    <!— navi —>
                    <div class=“navbar”>
                        <div class=“navbar-inner”>
                            <div class=“center”>
                                <div class=“list-block”>
                                    <div class=“item-inner”>
                                        <div class=“item-input”>
                                            <input type=“text” placeholder=“ Suchbegriff” style=“width: 100%; border-radius:5px; font-size: 13px;”>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div><!— navbar inner —>

                    </div><!— navbar —>
                    <div class=“toolbar tabbar tabbar-scrollable”>
                        <div class=“toolbar-inner”>
                            <a href=“#tab-1” class=“tab-link active” style=“color: black;”>Link 1</a>
                            <a href=“#tab-2” class=“tab-link” style=“color: black;”>Link 2</a>
                            <a href=“#tab-3” class=“tab-link” style=“color: black;”>Link 3</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class=“page-content”>
                        <div class=“swiper-container”>
                            <div class=“swiper-wrapper”>
                                <!— Tabs —>
                                <div class=“tabs”>
                                    <div id=“tab-1” class=“tab active swiper-slide”>
                                        <div class=“content-block”>
                                            content1
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id=“tab-2” class=“tab swiper-slide”>
                                        <div class=“content-block”>
                                            content2
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id=“tab-3” class=“tab swiper-slide”>
                                        <div class=“content-block”>
                                            content3
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!— Tabs ende —>

                            </div>
                        </div><!— swipe —>
                    </div><!— page content —>
                </div><!— div class home —>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type=“text/javascript” src=“js/framework7.js”></script>
    <script>
        var myApp = new Framework7({
        material: true,
        statusbarOverlay: false
        });
        var mySwiper = new Framework7();
        var mySwiper = mySwiper.swiper('.swiper-container', {
        pagination:'.swiper-pagination'
        });
    </script>
    <script type=“text/javascript” src=“cordova.js”></script>
</body>
```

Here is my custom `CSS`:

```
/* framework7.material.css custom */

.navbar, .toolbar {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
}

.tab-link {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 8px;
}

.tabbar a.tab-link,
.tabbar a.link {
    font-size: 12px;
}

.item-input {
    color: #000;
}

.center {
    width: 100%;
}


/* eigene stylesheets */

.contactscontainer {
    width: 100%;
}

.contactstext {
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
    font-size: 13px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.contactsbutton {
    float:right;
    width: 15%;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top: -15px;
}


.mynetcontainer {
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.myneticon {
    width: 10%;
    float: left;
    vertical-align: top;}

.mynettext {
    width: 90%;
    float: right;
    vertical-align: top;
}


.mediathekcontainer {
    width: 100%;
}

.mediathekpic {
    float: left;
    width: 35%;
    margin-top: 3px;
}

.mediathektext {
    float: left;
    width: 65%;
}


/* Swiper */

.swiper-container {
    height: 100%;
}
.swiper-slide {
    background:#fff;
}
.swiper-slide span {
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
    margin:20px;
    font-size:21px;
}
```

Comment: Which version of framework7 are you using?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: my college build a solution with jquery. Iam sorry, i haven‘t access to the code yet.